# How can I input 2 different variables on the same line while using setw for formatting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, formatting

Im using MSVS 2015 C++

this is what im working with. I got everything done except when i run it, after entering the seafood type, it jumps down to next line instead of going to the right for me to input the ppp under that heading. Ive tried everything i can think of, but I am fairly new to all of this. Any suggestions?
  [link to img of C++ code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyqCo.png)

Comment: I know the issue is on line 30 with the getline, but im just not sure how to code it to get the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

When applied to an `istream` (such as `cin`), the semantic of the manipulator `setw` is to set the maximum number of characters that can be accepted for the next input.

Thus `getline(cin,type) >> setw(23) >> pricepp` doesn't move the cursor 23 characters to the right as you expected: it enforces the constraint that at most 23 characters shall be read from `cin` into `ppp`.

The I/O libraries are filled with such subtle details, and take some time to master. See [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/132-input-with-istream/) for a tutorial that will give you more examples.